# Add only specific subdirectory of an include path to includes

Tags: c++, gcc, include-path, avr-gcc

I have a project which is built using cmake.
This project is uses avr-gcc to compile the binaries and I use boost mpl for some parts of it.

As avr-gcc does not have /usr/include as a default include path but boost is installed there, I need to add it as an include path such that boost is found.
Unfortunately, adding -I/usr/include to the command line pulls in all other files and directories in /usr/include which seems to introduce collisions with the avr includes and thereby compiler errors.

My initial solution involved a softlink to /usr/include/boost in one of my user defined include directories to resolve the

```
#include <boost/mpl/*>
```

However, I thought this to be not very platform independent and decided for cmake to add the include path for boost. This again led to "-I/usr/include" being present on the compiler command.

How do I solve this in a platform agnostic manner?

A solution would be to let cmake create the link for me to get the right include directory.
However, I consider the whole symbolic link solution ugly.
Is there something better that I can do?

For example: Is there some option that adds an include path under an alias like:

```
-I/usr/include/boost:boost
```

Which would add only the boost subfolder under the name boost to be includable by the `#include <boost/...>` directive?

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two options for you:

1. Where does `avr-gcc` include files from by default?  Let's say it is `/opt/avr-gcc/include` for concreteness.  Then what may work for you is `-I/opt/avr-gcc/include -I/usr/include`.
2. Another option is to install Boost in a different directory and use that instead of the Boost in `/usr/include`.  For example, you might create `/opt/boost` and then use `-I/opt/boost` (or a sub-directory under that) on the command line.

Comment: Option two is not available because I cannot control all computers where this ought to work. Option one seems to rely on the include directory for avr which I also cannot control on all systems.

Comment: Then you're probably snookered.  Bad luck.  You have to be able to control enough of the environment to be able to make decent builds.  Actually, I don't see why Option 2 is a problem.  If you're compiling code, you have a directory where you can place the Boost code — any suitable sub-directory of your source tree.  You only need it at compile time.  Include Boost as part of the source you're building.  Don't use the unreliable and uncontrollable version that happens to be on the system; use the version that's distributed with your software.

Comment: Packing 100mb of boost into the <1mb of sources seems like overkill if you can assume that boost will be installed on the system and that the version is sufficient for our purposes. I will probably go with the cmake generated symlink solution, but I have no idea how to generate this symlink before the compilation starts.